# Apache Basic Auth Hide user details in history

Tags: javascript, apache, authentication, redirect, basic-authentication

I'm working on a way to login into a password protected page using

http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@Domain.com/protected.html

I have a form where the user inserts then Username and Password, then on submit the javascript redirects you to the URL based on that info. This works great, the issue is when browsing through your history you can see the username and password.

Is there a way to re-direct and hide the users info? I've tried location.replace, but obviously that doesnt save the URL you are coming from.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Once you've stored the username and password in the URL you're at the mercy of how the web browser implements or handles web history. I should also add that some work/corporate environments may even have policies to clear down or prevent users from clearing the history.

If you want users to automatically login you need to think about implementing a "remember me" cookie, but don't forget to stick the authentication process over HTTPS otherwise your users will get [firesheep'd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep)